# Trying to get property of non-object error in PHP

Tags: php, pdo, syntax-error, notice

I'm trying to save my data using php. This is how I tried:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["MemberID"])) header("Location:logout.php");
include '../config.php';
include '../momdb.php';

$page_title = "Customers";
$mode = "Save";
$db = 'db';
$showmessage = false;
$message = "";
if (isset ( $_POST ["btnSave"] )) {
    $data = new table ();
    $data->MomID = $_POST ["CustomerID"];
    $data->CustomerName = $_POST ["CustomerName"];
    $data->FromDate = string_to_date ( $_POST ["FromDate"] );
    $data->ToDate = string_to_date ( $_POST ["ToDate"] );
    $data->CreatedBy = $_SESSION["MemberID"];
    $data->CreatedDatetime = date ( "Y-m-d H:i:s" );
    $data->LastModifiedBy = $_SESSION["MemberID"];;
    $data->LastModifiedDatetime = date ( "Y-m-d H:i:s" );

    $rows = array ();
    if (intval ( $data->CustomerID) > 0) {
        $rows = $db::Update ( $data );
    } else {
        $rows = $db::Save ( $data );
    }
    if (intval ( $rows ["WebID"] ) > 0) {
        $date = new DateTime ();
        header ( "Location: customerlist.php?msg=yes&msgt=s&t=" . $date->getTimestamp () . "&mtext=Record saved successfully" );
    } else {
        $showmessage = true;
        $message = $rows ["Message"];
    }
} elseif (isset ( $_GET ["CustomerID"] )) {
    $data = $db::GetByID ( $_GET ["CustomerID"] );
    if ($data == false) {
        $data = new table ();
        $data->CustomerID = 0;
    }
}

if ($data->CustomerID == "0")
    $mode = "Save";
else
    $mode = "Update";
?>
```

This code is for sending my values to the db page for saving them in the DB. I've used the PDO method. This is the first time I'm saving the record this way. That's why there is lots of confusion. The following code shows the Save() method, which I used to save the values to the DB.

```
public function Save(table $customer) {
        $data = new DB ();
        $stmt = $data->connection->prepare ( "CALL proc_CreateCustomer  (:CustomerName, :FromDate,:ToDate,:CreatedBy, :CreatedDatetime, :LastModifiedBy, :LastModifiedDatetime)" );
        $stmt->bindParam ( ':CustomerName', trim ($customer->CustomerName ));
        $stmt->bindParam ( ':FromDate', $customer->FromDate );
        $stmt->bindParam ( ':ToDate', $customer->ToDate);
        $stmt->bindParam ( ':CreatedBy',$customer->CreatedBy );
        $stmt->bindParam ( ':CreatedDatetime', $customer->CreatedDatetime );
        $stmt->bindParam ( ':LastModifiedBy',$customer->LastModifiedBy );
        $stmt->bindParam ( ':LastModifiedDatetime', $customer->LastModifiedDatetime );
        $stmt->execute ();
        $record = $stmt->fetch ( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
        if ($record == false) {
            return array (
                    "WebID" => 0,
                    "Message" => $record->Message,
                    "AppID" => $customer->AndroidID 
            );
        } else {
            return array (
                    "WebID" => $record->CustomerID,
                    "Message" => $record->Message,
                    "AppID" => $customer->AndroidID 
            );
        }
    }
```

This is how I've tried. But, whenever I try to save the details, it shows: " `Trying to get property of non-object in D:\Workspace\Application\momdb.php on line 39`", ie it shows error in the line `"Message" => $record->Message,"AppID" => $customer->AndroidID`. I don't what's wrong with this. Can someone tell me what should I change so that it work fine?

Comment: use print_r($record) and post the results here

Comment: I could be mistaken but it looks like Message does not exist in your stmt call unless that comes from proc_CreateCustomer.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($record == false) {
    return array (
            "WebID" => 0,
            "Message" => $record->Message,
            "AppID" => $customer->AndroidID 
    );
}
```

In this piece of code `$record` is false(y), so `$record->Message` doesn't exist.